# How Spring MVC send view result with data to ajax code?

Tags: javascript, java, ajax, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I have a Spring MVC application and I am developing a timed quiz. I am using the Thymeleaf for the formation of the final page that the user sees. I wish I could return the processing done by Thymeleaf (vision / resulting page) to the client side, and also pass the time available for the resolution of the question to a JavaScript code.

In short, the Thymeleaf processes the vision, returning a page with the question and options to choose from, and Spring MVC returns to JavaScript code the amount of time the user has to solve the question.

The biggest problem I have is that I can give something back to JavaScript code with @ResponseBody by a message in JSON, for example. But on the server side, I just can return or a vision, or data, not both at the same time.

I could return the contents of the question, the text and the choices together as JSON response (with time of the question), but then I would be taking the work from Thymeleaf, letting JavaScript code to solve the presentation, mixing in this case, different jobs...

Is there a way to respond JavaScript code using Thymeleaf with these criteria in mind? Allowing processing presentation and return information to the client side?

**OBS:** If you need some sample code, put a comment and I'll be happy to edit my question (although I think there is no need for it ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am afraid you can only send either one at a time. Each response from web server should be of a specific content type, for view it will be `text/html` for JSON it is `text/json`. Though, You can send separate requests for the view as well as for JSON data using ajax.

Comment: I think you're right. In this case, I could "solve" the problem by sending two server responses. The first page is processed by Thymeleaf. When the client receives the page (quiz page), JavaScript code hides the question, and send a request (AJAX) to the server asking the question time. The server then returns a second response, when received, the JavaScript code reveals the question and begins the time. I'd like your opinion. Would this be a wrong implementation? What do you think?

Comment: this sounds good.. just one additional thought, if you have security in mind, you should get the question as well as time using ajax together in one request. (coz, an attacker can check the source code and get the question, at the same time, if he can somehow delay the ajax call for time, he will get extra time!)

Comment: In my particular case, this is not a problem (in part, I guess), but... In the end, you suggest me to do what I said in my question, right? Allowing JavaScript to care of the presentation, as well as the functioning of the questions itself, leaving Thymeleaf aside (I say, for exchanging data, for example, with JSON)? Please feel free to be honest.

Comment: In fact, no matter what happens, a client can change it anyway on his side. In security questions, it is not advisable to create no validation or limitation on the client side, for it anyway could (with knowledge and tools) change this. The server would never know if it took 10, 20 or 1 million seconds to answer something. So, in a way, I do not worry about it. Now I just am not sure whether to send two responses to the user can impact on system performance. On the one hand, maintainability. On the other, performance. In this case, it's up to me to know what's best for my system. Thank you.

Comment: sending one more request won't impact perfomance (your browser is sending multiple requests anyways, like for css, js, images etc.., so this will be just another request)). If you are still worried about sending two requests, can you add the time information in the Thymelef itself. You can put it in a hidden input field or something and your JS can read the value on page load.